# Magento 2 How to save category selector data for custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, category-selector

I've used below code to show category selector on custom module. Its show wihout any error. Below is code for showing category selector on form.

```
$fieldset->addType(
        'categories',
        '\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Category'
);




$fieldset->addField(
        'category',
        'categories',
        [
            'name' => 'category',
            'label' => __('Category'),
            'title' => __('Category')
        ]
    );
```

I've save data using controller using below code as its array i need to convert it in string to save.

```
if ($data['category']):
  $data['category'] = implode(",",$data['category']);
endif;
```

its saved successfully. but when i edit data its thorow me error.

```
[2017-05-03 12:54:58] report.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 2930' in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
```

Am i missing something here?

Update:

below is form code:

```
class Main extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
     */
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
     * @param array $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Item Information');
    }


    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Item Information');
    }


    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this    
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_kensium_advisor_items');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('item_');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Item Information')]);
        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
        }
        $fieldset->addType(
        'categories',
        '\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Category'
       );

    $fieldset->addField(
            'advisor_name',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'advisor_name',
                'label' => __('Name'),
                'title' => __('Name'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );
```

**Update:**
I've updated code here for module.

https://github.com/kul3101/Category-Selector/tree/master/Test/Category/app/code/Test/Category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found issue was not selector but image saving.while edit i've images data in array so now i've added condition

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
//logic
}else if (isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == '1') {
// Logic
}else{

  $data['image'] = $data['image']['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set as an array when you edit like this

```
  $data['category'] = explode(",",$data['category']);
```

Comment: sorry. I didn't get you. I need to place it on edit.php of controller?

Comment: Before binding  your form and data. If you still confuse then show your form code here

Comment: Please check i've update form code.

Comment: have you checked my updated question?

Comment: Hey @Kul need to build exact same environment then test. It will be great if you share your module or when I have enough free time to build same module.

Comment: see code here https://github.com/kul3101/Category-Selector/tree/master/Test/Category/app/code/Test/Category